# Como hago para hacer un Intent dentro de cuerpo de una notificación en android?

Tags: java, android

```
public class PushNotificationsAdapter
    extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PushNotificationsAdapter.ViewHolder>{

ArrayList<PushNotification> pushNotifications = new ArrayList<>();

public PushNotificationsAdapter() {
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Context context = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_notification, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}

public void onButtonClick(View view)
{
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.ciberesquina.una.edu.ve/evaluacion/");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: ¿podrías explicar un poco más el problema que estás teniendo? ¿Qué error te da?

Answer (score 3):

Para realizar un `Intent` dentro de una Push Notification se realiza mediante un `PendingIntent`, te agrego un ejemplo:

```
public static void creaNotificacion(long when, String notificationTitle,
                                      String notificationContent, String notificationUrl, Context ctx) {
    try {

        Intent notificationIntent;


        Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(),
                R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        int smalIcon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;

        /* Valida la url y crea un Intent */
        if (!"".equals(notificationUrl)) {
            notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse(notificationUrl));
        } else {
            notificationIntent = new Intent();
        }

        /* Crea PendingIntent */
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0,notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        /* Construye la notificacion */
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                ctx).setWhen(when).setContentText(notificationContent)
                .setContentTitle(notificationTitle).setSmallIcon(smalIcon)
                .setAutoCancel(true).setTicker(notificationTitle)
                .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        notificationManager.notify((int) when, notificationBuilder.build());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Notificacion", "createNotification::" + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

de esta forma llamas el método para crear la notificación:

```
creaNotificacion(0,"Notificación Android!","Como llamar a una alerta o notificación para el usuario en la aplicación de Android?", "http://es.stackoverflow.com", getApplicationContext());
```

Al abrir la notificación desde la barra de notificaciones y puedes ejecutar una acción por medio de un PendingIntent, en este ejemplo abrira un url.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Cómo suplemento a lo que ha puesto @Elenasys, también se pueden agregar botones de acción a la notificación desde la api 4.1. Para ver los conceptos básicos acerca de la notificación, consulta la [documentación de android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).

```
Intent notificationIntent;

/* Valida la url y crea un Intent */
if (!"".equals(notificationUrl)) {
    notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://www.ciberesquina.una.edu.ve/evaluacion/"));
} else {
    notificationIntent = new Intent();
}

 /* Crea PendingIntent */
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0,notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

 Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(),
            R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    int smalIcon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setSmallIcon(smalIcon)
        // añadimos los botones que queramos, cada uno con su pending intent
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_web, "Ir a", pendingIntent ) 
        .setContentTitle("Nueva notificación")
        .setContentText("Ejemplo notificación con botón")
        .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
        .build();

    notificationManager.notify((int) when, notification);
```